# SP 2013 stuck in read only mode

Tags: 2013, maintenance

Tried running commands as Farm Admin:

When I run :

```
$site.GetType().GetProperty("MaintenanceMode").GetSetMethod($true).Invoke($site, @($false))
```

I get an error:

> Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): 
>   "Failed to update database "Content_Collab" because the database is
>   read-only."

Any ideas why this won't run without errors?

Comment: are you have RTM verson ? what's the latest CU installed in your farm ?

Comment: did you check if database is really read-only in SharePoint or SQL server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, when a maintenance not completed successfully then it put the Sites/DB in read only mode. to clear this mode please runt he below command.

```
$Admin = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteAdministration(‘http://weburl/sites/sitecollectionurl’)

$Admin.ClearMaintenanceMode()
```

[Read more here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/05/16/sharepoint-2013-site-in-read-only-mode-after-an-interrupted-backup/)

If that is not the case then check couple of thing son the

- SQL server has enough space on data drive
- Database is not marked as read only at SQL
- From central admin, it is not marked read only