# SharePoint site is lock

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, powershell-script

I ran below script to unlock SP site.

```
$admin = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteAdministration (“Site-Collection-URL”)
$admin.ClearMaintenanceMode()
```

Getting below error message when i run above script

```
> Exception calling clearmaintenance().Failed to update database
> "<Content DB>".Because the database is read only
```

When i check the Content DB, its all set as readwrite mode. Not in readonly mode

Comment: are you using the SQL Always-On?

Comment: Its in SQL Always On

Comment: Check if you are connected to primary SQL Server not the secondary?

Comment: Yes I am connecting to primary SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Run the PowerShell with administrator.

Check the following settings:

1. SQL server has enough space on data drive.
2. Database is not marked as read only at SQL.
3. From central admin->Application Management->Configure quotas and locks->choose the site collection, make sure the site collection is not locked.

Manage the lock status for site collections in SharePoint Server:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/manage-the-lock-status-for-site-collections

Similar issue post for your reference:

[SP 2013 stuck in read only mode](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200323/sp-2013-stuck-in-read-only-mode)

Comment: SQL server data drive has enough space and the database not marked as "Read Only"
But in SharePoint central admin page, the respective web application marked as "Read Only"